# How to get id from url to use in relationship database?

Tags: python, django

Sorry if the title does not make sense but I am a little unsure what it is i am after.

I have a locations page that list all the locations, which you can click on to bring up more info on that location and puts the id of the location into the url. From the location page I want to be able to add multiple assessments to that location. I have added a one to many relationship field in the assessment model but that brings up a drop down menu. I want it to automatically add the assessment to the location if the assessment link was clicked from the location page.

url.py

```
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/locations/all/$', 'assessments.views.locations'),
    url(r'^locations/get/(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', 'assessments.views.location'),
    url(r'^locations/get/(?P<location_id>\d+)/assessments/all/$', 'assessments.views.assessments'),
    url(r'^locations/get/(?P<location_id>\d+)/assessment1/(?P<assessment1_id>\d+)/$', 'assessments.views.assessment1'),
```

modules.py

```
class Location(model.Models):
    # some fields on the location

class Assessment(model.Models):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    assessment1 = models.CharField()
    assessment2 = models.CharField()
    assessment3 = models.CharField()

class Assessment1(model.Models):
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(Assessment)
    # some fields in assessment

ect
```

views.py

```
def locations(request):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/locations.html', {'locations': Location.objects.all() })

def location(request, location_id=1):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/location.html', {'location': Location.objects.get(id=location_id) })

def assessments(request):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/assessments.html', {'assessments': Assessments.objects.all() })

def assessments1(request, assessment1_id=1):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/assessment1.html', {'assessment1': Assessment1.objects.get(id=assessment1_id) })
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you need `Assessment` and a separate `Assessment1` model...

Comment: multiple categories make up one assessment and there can be multiple of the same category to one assessment

Comment: You should implement the assessment category in a separate field with [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) set. That way all types of assessment are in the same model, they only differ by their category field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restructure your models like this:

```
class Location(model.Models):
    ...

class Assessment(model.Models):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    ...

class Category(model.Models):
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(Assessment)
    ...
```

And have your routes be more like this:

```
url(r'^locations/$', 'views.locations'),
url(r'^locations/(?P<location_id>\d+)$', 'views.location'),
url(r'^locations/(?P<location_id>\d+)/assessments$', 'views.assessments'),
url(r'^locations/(?P<location_id>\d+)/assessments/(?P<assessment_id>\d+)$', 'views.assessment'),
url(r'^locations/(?P<location_id>\d+)/assessments/(?P<assessment_id>\d+)/categories$', 'views.categories'),
```

Then it will be much easier identifying the ids of the locations, assessments and categories in the views:

```
def locations(request):
    locations = Location.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('dashboard/locations.html', {'locations': locations})

def location(request, location_id):
    location = Location.objects.get(pk=location_id)
    return render_to_response('dashboard/location.html', {'location': location})

def assessments(request, location_id):
    location = Location.objects.get(pk=location_id)
    assessments = Assessment.objects.filter(location=location)
    return render_to_response('dashboard/assessments.html', {'assessments': assessments})

def assessment(request, location_id, assessment_id):
    location = Location.objects.get(pk=location_id)
    assessment = Assessment.objects.get(pk=assessment_id, location=location)
    return render_to_response('dashboard/assessment.html', {'assessment': assessment})

def categories(request, location_id, assessment_id):
    location = Location.objects.get(pk=location_id)
    assessment = Assessment.objects.get(pk=assessment_id, location=location)
    categories = Category.objects.filter(assessment=assessment)
    return render_to_response('dashboard/categories.html', {'categories': categories})
```

Comment: I think i am going around this completely the wrong way and explained it badly. Basically what i want is a simple one-to-many relationship table that automatically assigns what location that assessment belongs to

Comment: ok, what is confusing me are both the assessment1-2-3 instance variables and the Assessment1 class, why do you need those?

Comment: assessment1-2-3 was meant to be categories of one big assessment. A location can have many assessments and each assessment is made up of different categories. Does that make sense. Thanks you by the way.

Comment: can we begin by removing the Assessment1 class, it is really confusing :) do you want a structure like Location <- Assessment <- Category then, where the arrows are to-many-relationship.

Comment: Thats it. I just hope the rest i was trying to say makes sense now

Comment: @ChrisMeek updated the answer. does this start to solve your problem or is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your patients and help:D

Comment: No problem Chris, any time :)